# wp 8 phonegap 3.1 app no internet issue once downloaded to actual device

Tags: ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

Not sure how exactly to go about this one. I have a phonegap app that was initially created for ios/android and that we have now ported to wp8. I'm using Visual Studio express 2012 for Windows Phone. I have included an internet check in there that makes use of an Ajax call to determine whether there is an active Internet connection.

All is working fine on the emulator, I have also downloaded an update which includes 3 additional emulators, all is fine.

App has been approved but when it is downloaded to the actual device, **the internet check fails even though Internet is working fine on the device**.

I have wasted my time trying to connect my Nokia Lumia 620 device to my computer to test on so I am unable to recreate the issue. The Windows 8 machine/ emulator, actual device all use a Wi-Fi connection. Also I have included InAppBrowser which is working, but I have noticed content not loading in there either (cannot find server or DNS error).

This is driving me nuts any help would be greatly appreciated!.

```
var connectionTimer = setInterval(doesConnectionExist,3500); //internet check
var tryConnectTimer = setInterval(tryingToConnect,1000); //trying to connect message animation

function doesConnectionExist() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
            type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                        clearInterval(connectionTimer);
            clearInterval(tryConnectTimer);
            init();
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
                if (x.status == 0) {
            document.getElementById("connection").style.display = "block"; //no internet
            }
        },
        timeout: 3000
    });
}
```

Update:
Turns out this has nothing to do with AJAX calls, we have another app that is also unable to connect to the Internet...app passed validation and works perfect on the emulator. Inapp browser works but content is also not loading/no Internet. The test device is a Nokia Lumia 620 not sure if it is the culprit, other Apps on the device and IE has Internet access *sigh*.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the WP8 emulator uses a different means of Internet access.

On the actual device the app needs to have the following set ID_CAP_NETWORKING in order to have Internet access..